# How to deal with the redirect and then parser redirected page? Using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom to parse some pages. Now I'm trying to parse this page
[LINK](https://www.globalsportsjobs.com/index.php/page/advsearchvacs/bb/1?command=setpage&pageno=1)

As you can see, it only works after you enter it a second time. I think it must be a redirect or cookie

As I couldn't do it using HTML, I'm trying to use RSS. But I need information that is only in HTML, specifically the location field
[RSS](https://www.globalsportsjobs.com/index.php/page/adv_rss/command/getfeed/feed/4a2a139494ad1c02b7df790877737575)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.globalsportsjobs.com/index.php/page/adv_rss/command/getfeed/feed/4a2a139494ad1c02b7df790877737575');

    $parsed_results_array = array();
    foreach($xml as $entry) {
        foreach($entry->item as $item) {
            // $parsed_results_array[] = json_decode(json_encode($item), true);
            $items['title'] = (string) $item->title;
            $items['description'] = (string) $item->description;
            $items['link'] = (string) $item->link;
            $items['location'] = ?????????????;
            $parsed_results_array[] = $items;
        }
    }
```

I need these fields

[image]

Comment: Grab the `guid` field from the RSS and use that as the URL to fetch the HTML.  Then parse the resulting HTML to get the location.

Comment: I thought about it! However, there are many results and Parser will be slow!
Is there no way to get it directly from HTML?
If you access the first link and press F5 you will see that the page loads, I believe the problem is Cookie.

Comment: If you don't want all of the results, how are you determining which ones you do want?